# Using value from nested class in comment of another nested class

Tags: java, javadoc

I use `Eclipse Version: Kepler` and want to use the value of `STR` in comment of `FIELD` in this code:

```
public class OuterClass {

    public static final class StaticNestedClass1{
        public static final String STR = "This is some text";
    }

    public static final class StaticNestedClass2{
        /**
        * {@value StaticNestedClass1#STR}
        */
        public static final String FIELD = "";
    }
}
```

But it does not work.I only see `{@value StaticNestedClass1#STR}`.Of course this line works as expected:

```
/**
* {@link StaticNestedClass1#STR}
*/
```

How I can use of `STR` as part of comment of `FIELD`? Obviously I do not want to move `STR` from `StaticNestedClass1` to `OuterClass`.

Comment: Is this happening on some ide?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I use Eclipse Version: Kepler Release.

Comment: Might be relevant: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=72139#c9

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis OK! It seems that is relevant.Thank you for your attention.

Comment: If this is a bug in the javadoc generator in eclipse, then a workaround may be to use a different generator; e.g. the Oracle `javadoc` command.

Comment: @StephenC But I do not how I can use javadoc command.

Comment: @hasanghaforian - Have you tried reading the documentation for the javadoc command?  That will explain it.